# JSON response with nested calculated key in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, jbuilder, jsonresponse

I have a model and I need to group some of relations and make json response.

For example i have Models:

```json
users: {
  orders
  ...
}

orders: {
  order_group
  items
  ...
}

items: { ... }

order_groups: { ... }
```

I need to return JSON of users with all uniq order_groups and all items in each order_group:

```json
users: [
  {
    order_groups: [
      {
        items: [ ... ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have jBuilder and [ALBA serializer](https://github.com/okuramasafumi/alba).

I'm thinking of choosing ALBA serializer but how to describe this structure of fields?
`order_groups` is calculated key with another calculated key `items` inside.

I cant make has_many association with calculated column. And I can't create serializer for `order_groups` model because it doesn't have relation with `items`

With jbuilder it will be much easier, but lot of people doesn't like it.
Trying to go with trends

Comment: Are you asking for a query? Do you have a query? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Also please add more than just some JSON examples. You need to add your models code with current relations.

Comment: I did show my models with relations. And my questions pretty clear on my opinion. How to serialize calculated nested field